# Find duplicates in Sharepoint using FAST

Tags: 2013, fast-search, fast

Since FAST computes a document signature for every document it indexes, is it possible to query FAST for all the documents having at least one duplicate in the index?

If yes, what would be the FQL query for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplication is handled query time, so there is no property which will allow you to count or filter on this. But I agree getting a list of all duplicates would be nice to clean up data.

If you query with trimming you will get a count per item letting you know the duplicates (fcount I think..but not 100% sure), but you would need to iterate all results to get this.

Comment: That's what I suspected, is there at least a way to include a filter on this fcount in a query?

Comment: Unfortunately the fcocount is just a count in the results, not a managed property. I guess you could create a refinable property where you assign the signature, and check the counts on the refiners. Could work but a bit cumbersome.